# DFT and Inverse DFT in Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, dft, opencv, frequency-domain

I have implemented DFT from [Vision & Graphics Group at the Faculty of Informatics and Information Technologies STU - Frequency domain filtration](https://vgg.fiit.stuba.sk/2012-05/frequency-domain-filtration-source/).

1. Tried taking dft for the three Channels(R, G and B) and reconstructed the original image by taking inverse dft for all three channels and merged them together, but the image reconstructed doesnot have the same contrast as the original image.

But while altering the flags used in the link as such

```
  dft(input, Complex, DFT_SCALE);
  dft(Complex, InverseDFTImage, DFT_INVERSE + DFT_REALOUTPUT);
  InverseDFTImage.converTo(InverseDFTImage, CV_8U);
```

The output is same as the input, but while applying Gaussian filter, there are few colour differences near the edges.


 1. Original Input Image 

 [image: Original Input image]


 2. Output without any filters(followed the Procedure in the link) 

 [image: Output without any filters(followed the Procedure in the link)]


 3. After applying Gaussian Low Pass Filter 

 [image: After applying Gaussian Low Pass Filter] 


 Can someone clarify this doubt.? 

 P.S Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MATLAB?

Comment: @Drazick: No I'm using OpenCV

Comment: Then sorry, I don't understand their implementation of DFT. Usually, doing DFT and then IDFT result with the same vector / matirx up to numerical inaccuracies.

Comment: to add to what @Royi said, i doubt that (even with single-precision IEEE `float` for the RGB bitmaps) the quantization error would add up through the FFT passes to become particularly visible.  them's are 24 honest mantissa bits.  and if the bitmaps have 64-bit `double` instead of float, then forget it.  the quantization noise floor is so many dB down that it will never build up to anything of consequence in the FFT and inverse FFT.

Comment: and as best as i can tell, by looking, the otherwise unprocessed FFT/iFFT output image appears a little bluer.  in the white images, lighthouse, buildings, fence, there seems to be less yellow light.  the original appears brighter.  it might be just a little darker, but it seems to me that the B bitmap got a slight boost or the R and G bitmaps got reduced by a very tiny amount(s).

Comment: I think it is due to the color image filtering, and other color spaces may be more proper.

Comment: I have no clue what is going on, but here are a few thoughts: A) Be sure that you check the magniture image after the inverse DFT. B) Make sure that your numbers are not clipped due to the integers (convert to double or something like that before the first operation). C) Your Gaussian just looks wrong - it seems as if you amplify high frequencies. Check if you have the DC component in the middle of the spectrum and if you have the maximum value of the Gaussian at the same position, too.

Answer (score 2):

I saw same issue, and I found the answer in [stackoverflow - DFT to spatial domain in OpenCV is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646652/dft-to-spatial-domain-in-opencv-is-not-working).
for short, you can set imaginary part of filtering kernel zeros before you call mulSpectrums.

```
Mat planes[] = {Mat::zeros(dftImage1.size(), CV_32F), Mat::zeros(dftImage1.size(), CV_32F)};   
Mat kernel_spec;   
planes[0] = your_filter; // real     
// planes[1] = your_filter; 
// imaginar should be zero! Don't touch it.   
merge(planes, 2, kernel_spec);     
mulSpectrums(...
```

Hope this helps.